# Proportion Comparison

Tags: statistical-significance

I have data from baseline and end line surveys. Baseline was conducted before intervention in children and end-line was conducted after intervention in the same population. Study population is same for both surveys, as evident, however, data in end-line is not collected from same children ( who were assessed in baseline), rather it was random. 
Now I am assessing whether there is a significant difference between baseline and end-line proportions (% answers or children) in different indicators. I wonder whether I will use one sample or two sample proportion significant different test.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a two sample t-test.

However, you should know that this is a very weak design and you will not be able to conclude much from the result of this (or any other) statistical test on a simple pre- post- design on two different groups.